# What is parastate test network chain ID?

Tags: blockchain

I want to add Parastate tesnet to my metamask. I input this:
Network name: Parastate testnet
New RPC URL: https://rpc.parastate.io:8545/

But it also requires "Chain Id". Where can I find it or which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Network Name: ParaState

New RPC URL: https://rpc.parastate.io:8545

Chain ID: 123

Currency Symbol (Optional): STATE

Answer (score 0):

RPC URL: https://rpc.parastate.io:8545
Chain ID: 123
Currency Symbol: STATE
try it